# webpackをesbuildに変更した時のreact-railsで実装しているReactの修正方法を教えていただきたいです。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

## 実現したいこと

react-railsを使って部分的に読み込んでいるReactを、esbuildに変更した時に正常に読み込めるようにしたい

## 前提

Rails6、webpacker、react-railsで実装していたシステムをRails7にアップデートすることになり、それに伴いwebpackerからesbuildに変更することになりました。
Reactの知識が乏しく、調べてもreact-railsとesbuildを使用した方法が見つけられませんでした。
よろしくお願いいたします。

## 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

react-railsを使用して部分的にReactを読み込んでいましたが、
esbuildに変更してからのここの修正方法がわからず詰まっています。

```html
 = react_component('UserSkill', {id: current_user.id})
```

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react"
import axios from "axios"

const UserSkill = (props) => {
  const id = useState(props.id);
  const [skills, setSkills] = useState(props.search);

  useEffect(() => {
    async () => {
      const result = await axios(`/skills?id=${id}`);
      setSkills(result.data);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {skills.map((skill) => {
          <li key={skill.id}>
             {skill.name}
          </li>
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}

export default Skill
```

## 試したこと

package.jsonから読み込む様にしてみましたがダメでした。
reactのファイルはapp/javascript/components下にあります。

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "esbuild app/javascript/components/*.* app/javascript/packs/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --target=es2022 --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets",
    "build:css": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css  --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules"
  }
```

## ツールのバージョン

Ruby 3.1.0 → 3.1.3
Rails 6.1.6.1 → 7.0.4.2
react-rails 2.6.2
webpacker → esbuild

Answer (score 1):

react-railsはwebpackerでの使用を推奨しているようで、結局esbuildとの併用方法は見つからなかったため、大人しくesbuildで一緒にバンドルしてもらうことにしました。
ちなみにpackage.jsonに書いてもうまくいかなかったと書きましたが、こちらは記述方法が間違っていました。

```
  "scripts": {
"build": "esbuild app/javascript/packs/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --target=es2022 --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets && esbuild app/javascript/components/*.tsx --bundle --sourcemap --target=es2022 --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets --loader:.js=tsx",
"build:css": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css  --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules"}
```

esbuildの方は「読み込むフォルダ（ファイル）＋オプション」までをひと纏りとして &&で区切るようで、sassの方と同じ感覚で「フォルダ名 フォルダ名 ... オプション」としていたのがダメだったみたいです。
上記のように書いたところ正常に読み込まれました。